# Delegate from View Controller through Navigation Controller to Page Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, delegation

I have an Page View Controller containing two Navigation Controllers, which are embedding view controllers.

[image]

Is it possible to pass data directly from the View Controller to the Page View Controller. I want to use the delegation pattern, but I think then I am supposed to delegate to the navigation controller first which delegates to the Page View controller again. Does anybody know an less complex solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is wise to use protocols here, you're diving too deep, is it not possible to use notifications?

In your view that should call delegate function:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("yourNotification"), object: your object)
```

Then in your pageViewController viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourFuncName), name: NSNotification.Name("yourNotification"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad from your "PageViewController", add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(FooBar) name:@"FooBar" object:nil]; 
}

- (void) FooBar { 
NSLog(@"Foo"); 
};
```

Then call from the "ViewController"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FooBar" object:nil];
```